# Python Flask - login with email address, not username

Tags: python, email, authentication, flask

I want users to login with their email address, not with a username. How easy is it to do that with Flask ? Where can I find an example ?

Comment: Have you even bothered to look at Flask's docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Flask's flaskr example (exists in Flask git repo under examples) and rename the username there to email.